# How to resolve Error java: incompatible types: cucumber.api.DataTable cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Tags: java, cucumber

Hi I'm testing using cucumber currently and I'm a bit stumped the error message isn't helping me too much even after trawling the net I still can't find the correct solution.

```
   When company send us these XML messages   
     |fixtures/entitlements/sport_tennis.xml|
     |fixtures/entitlements/sport_golf.xml|

    @When("^company send us these XML messages$")
public void company_send_us_these_XML_messages(DataTable messages) throws Throwable {
   client.publish(messages);


   try {
       Thread.sleep(500);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
```

I'm currently getting the error message in the subject title.

```
Error java: incompatible types: cucumber.api.DataTable cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

How do I handle this datatable. The message doesn't really help I turn it into a string and it then tells me I need to Map it or make it into a data table. Are there any workarounds/solutions. This one has me stumped.

Comment: Try using [QMetry automation framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html). It supports data from excel, xml, csv, json or database. Refer [this feature file](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/resources/features/gherkin.feature). line 38: Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the step definition to this

```
public void company_send_us_these_XML_messages(List<List<String>> messages) {


}
```

You can loop through this to get your messages as a collection or a string to send to your method.